# entityCondition check if a field is not empty

Tags: database

My user table has an init field in it, it maybe empty or not.
I want to find all rows that are not empty
I tried

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
    ->addTag('role_filter');


function mymodule_role_filter_alter(QueryAlterableInterface $query) {
  $query->innerJoin('users_roles', 'ur', 'users.uid = ur.uid');  
  $query->innerJoin('role', 'r', 'r.rid = ur.rid');
  $query->condition('r.name', ['administrator', 'contributor', 'publisher'], 'IN');
  $query-> isNotNull(ur.init); // I ALSO TRIED a != '' condition
}
```

What I am doing now that works is:

```
  $results = $query->execute();

  $users_node_list = entity_load('user', array_keys($results['user']));

  $return_results = array();

  foreach ($users_node_list as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->init != ''){
```

but that is post query.

and read https://www.drupal.org/node/1157006

but this is not working (I don't get any results when I add this)

Ideas?

Comment: This question is not complete. Please show your entire query, so we can see better what is going on. Also look at [post #4](https://www.drupal.org/node/1157006#comment-5465034) of your linked page. That shows the trick for performing a join using an earlier added tag.

Comment: added needed code

Comment: And how do you process to results of the query? The more complete you are, the better we can help.

Comment: isn't this the entity load part?

Comment: I was referring to the part where you execute the query and process the results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by

```
$query->condition('field', '', '<>');
```

See: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Acondition/7.x

If this doesn't answer your question you need to. Be more specific.

Comment: what is the <> operator I cannot find any info about it

Comment: It is the non equal operator. See [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/723195/1293725) post for more information.

Answer (score 6):

In drupal 8, you can use the [exists](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Query%21QueryInterface.php/interface/QueryInterface/8.2.x) function like so :

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');    
$query->exists('field_x');
$results = $query->execute;
```